# How to use CSS with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to activate CSS using JS. Let's say I have this code, and I want to enlarge a picture at first click and then send it to the right after at the second click, but it's not working. Is the function correct?

**How can I use JavaScript to control the CSS of an element?**

```
<script>
    function function(){
        var house = document.getElementById("house");
            if(this.className == "mystyle")
                this.className = "mystyle2";
            else
                this.className = "mystyle";
    }
</script>

 <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none"><img src="casa1.jpg" id="house" width="200" height="150" onclick="function()">
```

I want it to activate this CSS:

```
.mystyle {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -100px;
}

.mystyle2{
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: You can't give a function the name "function". You should see an error in the browser console if you check (which you should).

Comment: I edited it, im having a diferent name actually.

Comment: Not really duplicate. As i do not know how to make the function do something else on second click.

Comment: you just place a counter variable for each click and check for the counter value on each click..

Comment: I tried it like this, but doesnt work : function functie(){
            var house = document.getElementById("house");
            var count;
            count++;
            if(count%2 == 1)
                house.className = "mystyle";
            else
                house.className = "mystyle2";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is good, but your scope is bad. Instead of `this` inside the function, you need to use `house`:

```js
function function1() {
  var house = document.getElementById("house");
  if (house.className == "mystyle")
    house.className = "mystyle2";
  else
    house.className = "mystyle";

}
```

```css
.mystyle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -100px;
}

.mystyle2 {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
  <img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/cute-house-clipart-house_clipart_12.gif" id="house" width="200" height="150" onclick="function1()">
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked great.

Answer (score 1):

Replace *this*, with *house*. In JavaScript *this* always refers to the “owner” of the function we're executing, or rather, to the object that a function is a method of. When you define your function function1() in a page, its owner is the page, or rather, the window object (or global object) of JavaScript. Otherwise looks good.